# MongoDb query on two collections

Tags: mongodb

I have two collection as below
First collection is
**Users**:

```
{
"userid":123,
"name":"abc",
"age":20,
"status":"Active"
}
{
"userid":345
"name":"cde"
"age":25,
"status":"Active"
}
```

second collection is
**userComment**:

```
{
"userid":123,
"commnet":"Mongodb rocks"
}
```

can anyone please help me writing the query to fetch the users with "Active" status alongwith a flag that will tell me whether user has any comment or not
So the o/p should be

```
{
"userid":123,
"name":"abc",
"age":20,
"status":"Active"
"userscommentFlag":"Y"**
}
{
"userid":345
"name":"cde"
"age":25,
"status":"Active"
"userscommentFlag":"N"
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the scheme from the models ?

Comment: If you are using mongo 3.2 latest version, you can use `$lookup` in the aggregation pipeline to join/populate fields from other collection.
See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB query multiple collections at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502541/mongodb-query-multiple-collections-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

Using `$lookup` in aggregation pipeline this can be done as:

```
db.users.aggregate(
[{$lookup:
 {from:"userComment", localField:"userid", foreignField: "userid", as: "comments"
}}])
```

Note: `$lookup` is supported in mongodb 3.2

Comment: In mongodb , if  you want to query from two collections , "$lookup" only used , its available in latest version

Comment: How I can add the "usercommentFlag" while using $lookup?