# MongoDB Query from Two collections

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections Players and Games:
i. Players contains player id from 1-15.
ii. Games contains games name:
    Hockey
    Cricket
    Badminton

with player id from 1-11 from "Players" collection.

Query for fetching all the games played by a specific player:
e.g. Player 4 plays how many games with games names.

Comment: You cant query two collection at once. First get player number from Players collection than in callback run query to get games for that player. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk - Please see $lookup - this feature in the aggregate pipeline is capable of doing outer joins - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB query multiple collections at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502541/mongodb-query-multiple-collections-at-once)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) - which can perform outer join on two collections, but you need mongodb version of 3.2 and also the two collections in your scenario `Players and Games` should be in same database.

References

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-2-of-3-worked-examples

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1077839/Working-with-MongoDBs-lookup-Aggregator