# Query multiple document types Spring Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

I am trying to extract multiple document types from Mongo database in a single query.  If I use find method it requires me to specify class type, and therefore restricting me to get only one document type.  For example if I have a collection that contains MongoDocumentA and MongoDocumentB, myList will get MongoDocumentA objects and any other documents will be nulls.  Is there anyway around this?

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("cir_group_status").ne(3).andOperator(Criteria.where("time").gte(startTime),Criteria.where("time").lt (stopTime)));
List myList = mongoOperation.find(query, MongoDocumentA.class);
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in MongoDB, let alone in Spring's Mongo. If it did exist in Spring, I bet it would just perform two queries.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502541/mongodb-query-multiple-collections-at-once) for some possible workarounds. It is not exactly the same problem as what you are trying to do, but I think the workarounds would be the same.

Comment: How come it is a limitation in MongoDB? If I do find in JavaScript I get result across all document types.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are describing?