# Query with join on mutiple collections with python in MongoDB

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I am newbie to MongoDB and Python (using pymongo 3.10.1). I can query one collection but I need to perform a join with two collections

```
collection1 {
    code
    some other fields
}

collection2 {
    code
    some other fields
}
```

I would like to achieve:
`select * from collection2 left inner join collection1 on collection2.code = collection1.code`

I found only basic examples for queries with Python to MongoDB.
How to achieve this with Python ? Could I use .aggregate and $lookup with Pythonn ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I get it working, here is the full code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

# connect to MongoDB, change the << MONGODB URL >> to reflect your own connection string
client = MongoClient(<< MONGODB URL >>)
db=client.mydb

docs = db.collection1.aggregate([{"$lookup":{
            "from": "collection2",       # other table name
            "localField": "code",        # key field in collection 2
            "foreignField": "code",      # key field in collection 1
            "as": "linked_collections"   # alias for resulting table
        }},
        {"$project": {"code": 1, "field_from_collection1": 1, "field_from_collection2": 1}}
        ])

#$project is to select fields we need, we could ommit it

for doc in docs:        
    print(doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I feel like there are two parts to your question:

How do you do more complicated queriers with pymongo?
How do you do a join with mongo?

The first question is pretty simple, you can declare any type of query and just use `find({<your query>})`. Here's an example from [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_query.asp)

The answer to your main question is more complicated. Here's another [stack article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502541/mongodb-query-multiple-collections-at-once) where it's talked about in more detail. But basically since 3.2 you can use `$lookup` to do joins.