# Searching for a user by email address in two collections in database MONGODB at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections `tutors` and `users` in my database mongodb. I have a `signin` function in the controller. Inside `signin` I have `tutors` and `users`. What condition should I add so that it searches for a user in both the `tutors` and `users` collections?

**controllers/auth**

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const Tutor = require('../models/tutor');

module.exports.signin = (req, res) => {
    const {email, password, remember} = req.body;

    //User
    User.findOne({email}).exec((err, user) => {
        if(err || !user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'User with that email does not exist. Please signup'
            });
        }

        if(!user.authenticate(password)) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Email and password do not match'
            });
        }

        const {_id, name, surname, email} = user;

        if (remember) {
            const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: '7d'});
            return res.json({
                token,
                user: {_id, name, surname, email}
            });
          } else {
            const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: '2m'});

            return res.json({
                token,
                user: {_id, name, surname, email}
            });
        }
    });


//tutor
Tutor.findOne({email}).exec((err, tutor) => {
        if(err || !tutor) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Tutor with that email does not exist. Please signup'
            });
        }

        if(!tutor.authenticate(password)) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Email and password do not match'
            });
        }

        const {_id, name, surname, email} = tutor;

        if (remember) {
            const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: '7d'});

            return res.json({
                token,
                tutor: {_id, name, surname, email}
            });
          } else {
            const token = jwt.sign({_id: tutor._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: '2m'});

            return res.json({
                token,
                tutor: {_id, name, surname, email}
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB query multiple collections at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502541/mongodb-query-multiple-collections-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way to design your database model. Instead create a single collection, call it `users` and it can have a field like `userType` that can be either `Tutor` or `User`

User model
User.js

```
var userSchema = {
        type: String,
        enum: ['tutor', 'user'],
        default: 'user'
}
```

and query like this:

```
Tutor.findOne(...) // to query for a tutor
User.findOne(...) // to query for a user
```