# How retrieve data from 3 different collections using single mongo db query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

looking for help

I have 3 different collections in mongo DB.

1.FormSubmissions
2.FormAnswers
3.FormQuestions

I want retrieve data from 3 different collections using mongo DB

**I want below response**

```
[
{
        "_id":{"$oid":"5f8d5e164f243b1d0e7c8a85"},
        "LanguageId":{"$oid":"5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"},
        "FormId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5"},
        "FormVersionId":{"$oid":"5e4d43c19ee80910ef49a21c"},
        "SubmittedOn":{"$date":"2020-10-19T09:36:22.737Z"},
        "EmployeeId":{"$oid":"5e50b0843bd4c66692ee72c0"},
        "Name":"1212",
        "Type":"Follow-up",
        
},
{
        "_id":{"$oid":"5f8d5c7d4f243b1d0e7c88d7"},
        "LanguageId":{"$oid":"5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"},
        "FormId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5"},
        "FormVersionId":{"$oid":"5e4d43c19ee80910ef49a21c"},
        "SubmittedOn":{"$date":"2020-10-19T09:37:22.737Z"},
        "EmployeeId":{"$oid":"5e50afd33bd4c66692ee72b5"},
        "Name":"1111",
        "Type":"NEW",   
}
]
```

**FormSubmissions collection data**

```
[
{
        "_id":{"$oid":"5f8d5e164f243b1d0e7c8a85"},
        "LanguageId":{"$oid":"5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"},
        "FormId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5"},
        "FormVersionId":{"$oid":"5e4d43c19ee80910ef49a21c"},
        "SubmittedOn":{"$date":"2020-10-19T09:36:22.737Z"},
        "EmployeeId":{"$oid":"5e50b0843bd4c66692ee72c0"},
},
{
        "_id":{"$oid":"5f8d5c7d4f243b1d0e7c88d7"},
        "LanguageId":{"$oid":"5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"},
        "FormId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5"},
        "FormVersionId":{"$oid":"5e4d43c19ee80910ef49a21c"},
        "SubmittedOn":{"$date":"2020-10-19T09:37:22.737Z"},
        "EmployeeId":{"$oid":"5e50afd33bd4c66692ee72b5"},
}
]
```

**FormAnswers collection data**

```
[{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5f8d5e164f243b1d0e7c8c27"},
    "FormId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5"},
    "FormVersionId":{"$oid":"5e4d43c19ee80910ef49a21c"},
    "FormSubmissionId":{"$oid":"5f8d5e164f243b1d0e7c8a85"},
    "LanguageId":{"$oid":"5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"},
    "Answers":[
        {
            "_id":{"$oid":"5f8d5e164f243b1d0e7c8a86"},
            "FormQuestionId":{"$oid":"5e4d476a9ee80910ef49a3d4"},
            "ElementType":11,
            "Value":"1212"
        },
        {
            "_id":{"$oid":"5f8d5e164f243b1d0e7c8a87"},
            "FormQuestionId":{"$oid":"5e4d476a9ee80910ef49a3d5"},
            "ElementType":8,
            "Value":"Follow-up"
        }
        ]
},
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5f8d5e164f243b1d0e7c8c27"},
    "FormId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5"},
    "FormVersionId":{"$oid":"5e4d43c19ee80910ef49a21c"},
    "FormSubmissionId":{"$oid":"5f8d5c7d4f243b1d0e7c88d7"},
    "LanguageId":{"$oid":"5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"},
    "Answers":[
        {
            "_id":{"$oid":"5f8d5e164f243b1d0e7c8a86"},
            "FormQuestionId":{"$oid":"5e4d476a9ee80910ef49a3d4"},
            "ElementType":11,
            "Value":"1111"
        },
        {
            "_id":{"$oid":"5f8d5e164f243b1d0e7c8a87"},
            "FormQuestionId":{"$oid":"5e4d476a9ee80910ef49a3d5"},
            "ElementType":8,
            "Value":"NEW"
        }
        ]
}]
```

**FormQuestions collection data**

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5f857076d1e44f6af1adb526"},
    "FormId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5"},
    "FormVersionId":{"$oid":"5e4d43c19ee80910ef49a21c"},
    "LanguageId":{"$oid":"5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"},
    "Questions":[
        {
            "_id":{"$oid":"5e4d476a9ee80910ef49a3d4"},
            "ElementType":11,
            "Question":"Name",
            "Index":0,
        },
        {
            "_id":{"$oid":"5e4d476a9ee80910ef49a3d5"},
            "ElementType":8,
            "Question":"Type",
            "Index":1,
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

looking for quick response.

Comment: mongodb version?

Comment: @Rushi dave MongoDB server version: 4.2.9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB query multiple collections at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502541/mongodb-query-multiple-collections-at-once)

Comment: @ AlexisG Thanks for answers.our questions collections nature is dynamically.it's not fixed schema